# How to call a different class from the app delegate (using SpriteKit) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I need to call a method in the `GameScene` class called `pause()` from a default method in my `AppDelegate` class called `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

In other words (in AppDelegate):

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Call GameScene method
}
```

And in GameScene class:

```
func pause() {
    // pause game     (this method works fine when called elsewhere in the program)
}
```

I need `pause()` to be called when the app enters the background.

`GameScene.pause()` did not work, but I don't understand why. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `GameScene.pause()` doesn't work because you are calling it on the class, not on the instance of the class, and it isn't a class method - it's an instance method. You need a reference to an instance of the class to call it. Where and how is your `GameScene` object instantiated?

Comment: `var scene: GameScene!` is in the `GameViewContoller` class. Then in the `viewDidLoad` method: `scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)`. I hope this answers your question!

Comment: Which means it isn't accessible in the `AppDelegate`, which is a different class.

Comment: So how can I fix this?

Comment: Hang on a sec, answer coming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution here is probably to use `NSNotificationCenter`, and avoid using the `UIApplicationDelegate` callback completely

Add the following to the `-viewDidLoad` of your `GameViewController`:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "appEnteredBackground:", name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)
```

*Note that the "appEnteredBackground:" argument string has a : on the end - if you miss this out this will not work (because then it will look for a method with no arguments*)

Add the following `deinit` destructor (or add the relevant line if you already have one):

```
deinit {
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Then implement the `-appEnteredBackground:` method on the `GameViewController`:

```
func appEnteredBackground(notification:NSNotification) {
  scene.pause()
}
```

The notification method should fire when the app enters the background

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem. You are a genius.

Comment: Thanks buddy! Helped a lot!

Comment: It's worth noting that you probably don't need the `deinit` method anymore. [Apple says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter) "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later, you don't need to unregister an observer in its dealloc method".